# Water off/ still leaking

Tags: water, leaks

My hot water leaks from the tub faucet only. We have shut the hot water off at the hot water heater and it is still leaking hot water. How do i fix this?

Comment: You do not say where the water is leaking from. I assume it is the spout?

Answer (score 1):

Hot and cold lines can communicate through single lever delivery faucets. But the shutoff valves will stop this. Turn off the hot supply at the shutoff at each single handle control. Usually it is the kitchen faucet doing this, but it can be any where.

Answer (score -1):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. the isolation tap is allowing some water through - if so then it needs replacing as well
2. the leaking tap is allowing air in and so the water still in the tap side of the system after the isolation tap is draing out as the air enters to replace it.

Replace one or both taps.